# Do repayment variables in the College Scorecard refer only to debt acquired as an undergraduate?

Tags: collegescorecard

Do the repayment variables in the College Scorecard refer only to debt acquired as an undergraduate, or do they include debt acquired in graduate programs as well? Also, do they refer only to debt acquired by students at a particular institution, or do they include debt acquired by students at other institutions as well?

Answer (score 2):

Repayment variables in the College Scorecard refer only to undergraduate debt acquired at the one institution for which the repayment rate is reported for.  Please note, the same student may be in repayment rate cohorts for multiple schools with the share of loans attributed to one school in that school's calculation, and the share of the loans attributed to another school in a different calculation.